# CNN predict always the same output

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am new to neural networks and I am working on prediction from images. I would like to predict 101 data points from an image. The images are made from data measured by sensors . I have tried the following code, but when I predict, I always get the same prediction. Any idea how to solve this problem? I also tried with more epochs, different layers, different activation functions and got the same problem.

```
Trainingfolder = 'C:\Users\sozan\Documents\SmartLocomotion\Dataset\Dataset1\Trainingset'  
Testfolder = r'C:\Users\sozan\Documents\Smart Locomotion\Dataset\Dataset1\Testset'  

image_files = [os.path.join(Trainingfolder, f) for f in os.listdir(Trainingfolder) if f.endswith('.jpeg')]

plt.figure()  
for i in range(5):
    imgfile = random.choice(image_files)
    img = image.imread(imgfile)
    outname = imgfile[0:-5] + ".mat"
    outfile = scipy.io.loadmat(outname, squeeze_me=True,struct_as_record=False)
    output = outfile['output'].AnkleFlexExt
    ax=plt.subplot(2,5,i+1)
    plt.imshow(img)
    ax=plt.subplot(2,5,i+1+5)
    plt.plot(output)
```

[dataset : the image is made from sensors data and the curve represent the output data that I would like to predict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFXws.png)

```
def create_dataset(datafolder):
    image_files = [os.path.join(datafolder, f) for f in os.listdir(datafolder) if f.endswith('.jpeg')]

    img_data_array = []
    output_data = []

    for imgfile in image_files:
        imag = image.imread(imgfile)
        imag = np.array(imag)
        imag = imag.astype('float64')
        imag /= 255 
        img_data_array.append(imag)
        outname = imgfile[0:-5] + ".mat"
        outfile = scipy.io.loadmat(outname, squeeze_me=True,struct_as_record=False)
        output = outfile['output'].AnkleFlexExt
        output_data.append(output)
       
    return img_data_array, output_data

img_Trainingdata, output_Trainingdata = create_dataset(Trainingfolder)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(101,9,3))) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu')) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3000, activation = 'relu')) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(101))

adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False);
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='mse', metrics=["mse"])

model.summary()
```

| Layer (type) | Output Shape | Param # |
| --- | --- | --- |
| conv2d_2 (Conv2D) | (None, 99, 7, 64) | 1792 |
| max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) | (None, 50, 4, 64) | 0 |
| conv2d_3 (Conv2D) | (None, 48, 2, 128) | 73856 |
| max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D) | (None, 24, 1, 128) | 0 |
| flatten_1 (Flatten) | (None, 3072) | 0 |
| dense_2 (Dense) | (None, 3000) | 9219000 |
| dense_3 (Dense) | (None, 101) | 303101 |

Total params: 9,597,749
Trainable params: 9,597,749
Non-trainable params: 0

```
history = model.fit(x=np.array(img_Trainingdata, np.float64), y=np.array(output_Trainingdata, np.float64), epochs=1)
```

36/36 [==============================] - 2s 55ms/step - loss: 0.0639 - mse: 0.0639

```
def load_Testdata(dataname):    

   img_data_array = []
   imag = image.imread(imgfile)
   imag = np.array(imag)
   imag = imag.astype('float64')
   imag /= 255 
   img_data_array.append(imag)
   return img_data_array

image_test = [os.path.join(Testfolder, f) for f in os.listdir(Testfolder) if f.endswith('.jpeg')]

plt.figure()

for itest in image_test:

    outname = itest[0:-5] + ".mat"
    outfile = scipy.io.loadmat(outname, squeeze_me=True,struct_as_record=False)
    output = outfile['output'].AnkleFlexExt
    plt.plot(output, color='blue', label='Measured')

for itest in image_test:
    
    img_test = load_Testdata(itest)    
    pred = model.predict (x=np.array(img_test, np.float64))
    pred = pred[0]
    plt.plot(pred, color='red', label='Predicted')


plt.title('Ankle Flex-Ext Moment')
plt.ylabel('Nm.kg$^{-1}$')
plt.xlabel('% cycle')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Are the training metrics correct? Could you share a little more information about the loss function values and metrics obtained during the training process so we can better help you?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Basically the Neural net is not learning anything at all. Irrespective of the code, the problem is at the data level. Please perform proper EDA and visualize whether the required data is fit to be given as an input to the network. Check for class imbalance as well. It should be at least 70-30 if not more.